# How to eliminate other post when i click the older post in the page below

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with my code how to put condition? in WP_Query to exclude the post which is newer than the specific date. Example when i click the page below:
and click "Swertres June 09, 2016" i dont want to include the result from june 10 - to the newest post

http://www.pcsodailyresult.com/swertres-june-28-2016/

```
if( in_category('17'))
{
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=17&showposts=20' ); 
}
else  if( in_category('18'))
{
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=18&showposts=20' ); 
}
else  if( in_category('16'))
{
    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=16&showposts=20' ); 
}
```

and so on.........